# Postgres throws error when running import from activerecord-import gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord-import

I switched to Postgres in development and now following error breaks a test case:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  column "id" of relation "assets_content_nodes" does not exist
:           SELECT pg_get_serial_sequence($1, $2)
```

Same error happens in development and production environments but it is not a show stopper and does not affect the import.
assets_content_nodes is a join table and I'd rather not add the 'id' column.
Any ideas why this may be happening?

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed in [activerecord-import -v0.3.1](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) (or possibly an earlier version, but it was broken in 0.2.11 and earlier).  You no longer need an `id` column on a table to do an import.

Answer (score 0):

You might also try [`Upsert`](https://github.com/seamusabshere/upsert).

If you're importing pets:

```
require 'csv'
require 'upsert'
u = Upsert.new Pet.connection, Pet.table_name
CSV.foreach('pets.csv', headers: :first_row) do |row|
  selector = { name: row['name'] }
  setter = row
  u.row selector, setter
end
```

My tests show it's 20–30% faster than `activerecord-import`. Since it's "upserting," it's generally OK if the process gets interrupted and you just start over from the beginning.